# How to click on a video when full screen mode is on in silverlight?

Tags: javascript, jquery, silverlight

I want to perform some operation when the user clicks on the video. When full screen mode is off, all things are working nicely but click event is not getting fired when full screen mode is on. Can anyone tell me why is it so?

Here is my code.

```
var obj = "<object id=\"video\" data=\"data:application/x-silverlight-2,\" type=\"application/x-silverlight-2\" width=\"" + width1 + "%\" height=\"" + height1 + "%\">" +
            "<param name=\"onLoad\" value=\"pluginLoad\" />" +
            "<param name=\"source\" value=\"player.xap\"/>" +
            "<param name=\"initParams\" value=\"sourceurl=" + url + "\" />" +
            "</object>";
```

and jQuery code is

```
$("body").on("mouseup", "#video", function (){
   console.log("clicked");
});
```

When I click on the video and full screen mode is off, "clicked" is getting printed but when full screen mode is on and I click, nothing is happening. Is something wrong with my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with two technologies here. Your Web application (HTML, CSS, JS) contains an embedded video player in an HTML-Object element. Whenever you click on that element, the defined click event will occur! The content doesn't matter.

If you switch to the "native" fullscreen mode of the plugin, you have left the context of your defined DOM click event.

All your clicks must now be handled by your silverlight component via "managed code".

I think you have 2 options now:

1. Use the Silverlight HTML bridge. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645076(v=vs.95).aspx

   This means: Register your click events in the silverlight code and call the JS functions from there
2. Use the HTML5 fullscreen mode (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode) and stretch your silverlight component to a height and width of 100%.

Regards
Rolf

Comment: Is there any example of option 1?

Comment: Did you click on the link I've provided in my answer? 
There is a 

Walkthrough: Calling JavaScript from Managed Code


http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221359(v=vs.95).aspx

There you can find an example